# it is impossible to access props until the hot update of the Vue JS + Quasar component occurs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, quasar

I have a component that receives props from the page component, which in turn receives parameters from the query parameters. The problem is that until the hot update happens, the form will be empty, just like the props. After I make some changes in the code and a hot update happens, everything becomes normal.

Page source code:

```
<template>
  <q-page class="bg-grey-3 column items-center">
    <SurveyEdit
    :question="question"
    :correctAnswer="correctAnswer"
    :choices="choices"
    />
  </q-page>
</template>

<script>
import SurveyEdit from 'src/components/SurveyEdit.vue'
import { onMounted, ref } from 'vue'
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router'

export default {
  name: 'EditPage',
  components: {
    SurveyEdit
  },
  setup() {
    const route = useRoute()
    const question = ref('')
    const choices = ref([])
    const correctAnswer = ref(null)
    const imageURL = ref('')
    onMounted(() => {
      const queryParams = route.query
      imageURL.value = queryParams.imageURL
      question.value = queryParams.question
      // console.log(question)
      if (queryParams.choices) {
        choices.value = queryParams.choices.split('|')
      }
      correctAnswer.value = Number(queryParams.correctAnswer)
    })
    return {
      question,
      choices,
      correctAnswer,
      imageURL,
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

SurveyEdit source code:

```
<template>
  <q-card class="survey-card" flat bordered>
    <img v-if="loaderModel" :src="imageURL">
    <q-form
      @submit="onSubmit"
      class="q-gutter-md"
    >
      <q-file clearable color="orange" standout bottom-slots
        label="Загрузить изображение для опроса"
        @update:model-value="onImageLoaded"
        v-model="loaderModel"
        class="image-loader"
      >
        <template v-slot:prepend>
          <q-icon name="attach_file" />
        </template>
        <template v-slot:hint>
          Для удаления изображения нажмите на крестик в правой части загрузчика
        </template>
      </q-file>
      <q-input
        filled
        v-model="question"
        label="Заголовок опроса *"
        hint=""
        lazy-rules
        :rules="[ val => val && (val.length > 0 || val.value.length > 0) || 'Пожалуйста, введите что-нибудь']"
      />
      
      <ul class="choices-list bg-grey-2">
        <q-input 
          v-for="(choice, index) in choices"
          filled
          label="Ответ *"
          v-model="choices[index]"
          hint=""
          lazy-rules
          :rules="[ val => val && (val.length > 0 || val.value.length > 0) || 'Пожалуйста, введите что-нибудь']"
          class="choice"
        >
          <template v-slot:append>
            <q-btn round dense flat icon="close" @click="() => {onDeleteChoice(index)}"/>
          </template>
          <template v-slot:after>
            <q-btn :class="{'bg-green-3': index==correctAnswerIndex}" round dense flat icon="check" @click="() => {onSelectCorrectAnswer(index)}"/>
          </template>
        </q-input>
      </ul>
      <div class="column items-center">
        <q-btn label="Добавить ответ" color="secondary" class="center" @click="onChoiceAdd"/>
      </div>
      <q-separator />
      <div>
        <q-btn label="Сохранить" type="submit" color="primary"/>
      </div>
    </q-form>
  </q-card>
</template>


<script>
import { ref, onMounted, defineProps } from 'vue'
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router'


export default {
  name: 'SurveyEdit',
  props: {
    imageURL: String,
    question: String,
    choices: Array,
    correctAnswer: Number,
  },
  setup(props) {
    console.log(props.question) // before hot update displays an empty string, after everything is fine
    const question = ref(null)
    question.value = props.question 

    const choices = ref([])
    for (let choice of props.choices) {
      choices.value.push(choice)  
    }
    const correctAnswerIndex = ref(null)
    correctAnswerIndex.value = props.correctAnswer

    const imageURL = ref('')
    const loaderModel = ref(null)
    onMounted(() => {

    })
    return {
      loaderModel,
      imageURL,
      question,
      choices,
      correctAnswerIndex,
  
      onImageLoaded(image) {
        if (image) {
          imageURL.value = URL.createObjectURL(image)
        }
      },
      onSubmit() {
        console.log(question.value)
        console.log(choices.value)
        console.log(correctAnswerIndex.value)
      },
      onChoiceAdd() {
        choices.value.push(ref(''))
      },
      onDeleteChoice(index) {
        choices.value.splice(index, 1)
        if (index == correctAnswerIndex.value || correctAnswerIndex.value >= choices.value.length ) {
          correctAnswerIndex.value = null
        }
      },
      onSelectCorrectAnswer(index) {
        correctAnswerIndex.value = index
      }
    } 
  },
  
}
</script>
<style scoped>
.image-loader {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.choices-list {
  padding-left: 0px;
}
.choice {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
</style>
```

I'm new to Vue JS and maybe I don't fully understand its specifics of work.

Comment: I added this, and it seems to help, but it seems to me that the solution is not the best
`nextTick().then(() => {
      question.value = props.question;
      for (let choice of props.choices) {
        choices.value.push(choice);
      };
      correctAnswerIndex.value = props.correctAnswer;
    })`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your code is not running in the order you think it is.  You need to be aware of [component lifecycles](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/lifecycle.html#lifecycle-diagram), and when it comes to Parent and Child hooks it goes:

**Parent created --> Child created --> Child mounted --> Parent mounted**

This simple [Vue Playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#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) will confirm this if you open up your browser dev tools where you can see the order of the console logs firing from different hooks.

So it comes down to the fact that you're trying to console.log a prop value in the **Child created** hook, but the prop value isn't set until the **Parent mounted** hook which comes afterwards.

Vue component state can be preserved during hot reloading of your code, meaning the prop value from the first run now exists when console log executes during the second run.

A possible solution if you can't set the values you need in the Parent created hook, is to add a [watcher](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html) to your Child to run whatever code you want when it detects that the watched value (a prop in you case) is updated.

```js
setup(props) {
  console.log('created hook')

  watch(() => props.question, () => {
    // code here executes when props.question updates
  })
},
```

[updated Vue Playground example](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)